# VMWare workstation freezes, lags and khugepaged consumes 100% CPU in Ubuntu host

Tags: freeze, vmware-workstation

Sometimes VMWare workstation lags (stuttering) or even freezes and often even freezes my host operating system. Usually this happens when under high load of the CPU or the GPU. In many cases typing text in the guest OS can trigger stuttering behaviour.

When freezing, the processes `vmware-vmx` and `khugepaged` get 100% cpu time for a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This is not my solution (I don't know what the consequences of disabling `khugepaged` are) but it worked for me:

> The khugepaged is the process that configures the transparent hugepages. When i disable the transparent hugepages windows guest run without freezes again. To disable it on every operating system start up i put in /etc/rc.local

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
    echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
    echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
```

Source: http://unversioned.blogspot.be/2015/10/vmware-workstation-11-ubuntu-high-cpu-utilization.html

EDIT: in hindsight this only seems to *reduce* the amount of freezes, but they still do occur. Especially when closing and then re-opening the VM, and strangely also especially when running simultaneously having Firefox open ...